# Importance of Packages and Modules in Python and how to Import any module

Tags: python

Needs of Python Packages and Module

What is Package? and what is module?
How Importance is this topic in python?
what is the Main advantages of this?
How we can access this in any real time projects?

Expecting easy understanding and control flow of this Packages and Modules

Comment: Have you attempted looking it up before asking here? This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Python packages and modules are a hugely important topic in Python. Python is a language that is hugely about keeping things simple and easy to read.

Using packages and modules, you can access functions and objects written by other people to help you solve problems with code, without ever needing to understand the implementation of their code.

Here is a great resource on [packages and modules](https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#python-packages) on Real Python that will go in depth for you, at pretty much a beginner level understanding.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).